# convert R Sys.time() to hive timestamp data_type

Tags: r, hadoop, hive

I am writing some tables from R to csv to hive. One of the columns in hive table is of timestamp data_type. This basically contains timestamp value as shown below.

How can I convert sys.time() from character to something that can be stored in  hadoop as timestamp data_type?

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2020-02-24 18:22:33 EST"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2020-02-24 19:15:49 EST"
> as.character(Sys.time())
[1] "2020-02-24 19:15:58"
```

The reason above works is because hive timestamp uses very specific input format as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". The best way to achieve it in R is to use as.character.